# Write Logfiles to Slow Disk or sending Tomcat Access Logs to ElasticSearch?

Tags: kubernetes, tomcat, logging, logback

- My service (tomcat/java) is running on a kubernetes cluster (AKS).
- I would like to write the log files (tomcat access logs, application logs with logback)  to an AzureFile volume.
- I do not want to write the access logs to the stdout, because I do not want to mix the access logs with the application logs.

**Question**

I expect that all logging is done asynchronously, so that writing to the slow AzureFile volume should not affect the performance.
Is this correct?

**Update**

In the end I want to collect the logfiles so that I can send all logs to ElasticSearch.

Especially I need a way to collect the access logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send your access logs to Elastic Search, you just need to extend the [`AbstractAccessLogValve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AbstractAccessLogValve.html) and implement the `log` method.

The `AbstractAccessLogValve` already contains the logic to format the messages, so you need just to add the logic to send the formatted message.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right but still here depends on how you are writing the logs. If asynchronously you are writing long process will take and your files system is slow. If it's NFS there is also the chance of network latency etc.

i have seen performance issues if attaching NFS & Bucket volume direct to multiple PODs.

If your writing is slow asyn thread might take time to complete job and take higher resources also however it still depends on code and way of written code.

Ideally, people use to store in Elasticsearch for fast retrieval easy management.

People use different stacks based on requirement but mostly all of them backed by elasticsearch for example Graylog, ELK.

For sending or writing logs to these stack people use the UDP I personally prefer GELF UDP and throws a logs at Graylog and forget.

Comment: Good point: In the end I want to use Elasticsearch. The problem is, that the logging options for the tomcat access logs are limited. Here it's not possible to use GELF as a target. And I don't like the idea to add filebeat to each of my pods. So I thought collecting the log files in a single NFS volume might be a good idea.

Comment: yes that's a good idea but i have never tried writing files to NFS, not sure how efficient tomcat is. i would suggest checking out MinIO & GlusterFS if you are looking for good NFS, they do support high IOPS write and read so chance not much issues will be there.

Comment: https://min.io/ check this out.

Comment: You can create a custom access log `Valve` by extending [`AbstractAccessLogValve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AbstractAccessLogValve.html), which already contains the formatting logic and send your logs to Elastic Search.

Comment: Sorry guys I should have asked better right from the start. I think the sugggest solution of Piotr fits better to my needs because I need no other tooling. @HarshManvar Anyway I appreciate your help and upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz I've updated my question, so that your suggestion fits as an answer. Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: yes, that looks pretty good, i have never worked around tomcat so not have much idea.

Comment: Hi @PiotrP.Karwasz , could you post your comment as an answer?